# android -Need some suggestion for making a viewpager for very big datas

Tags: android

I want to make a leitner application . the data is coming from database .

For instance , I've about 500 rows in my database and I want to make a viewpager for showing them , each row comes on one page so I'll have 500 pages in the viewPager .

The question is , What is the best way to implement something like this ? is it going to have memory problems or something ?

What are the better ways to do so ? if no other way ,What type of viewPager is better to use for database? A fragment viewAdapter for example

Comment: Just don't ! 500 pages for a view pager is a terrible idea for user experience. Use a listview with a search engine for exemple

Comment: @grunk you can add `search` / `filtering` for a ViewPager as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should use a normal `ViewPager` with [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).

As described in documentation

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number
>   of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to
>   the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the
>   saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much
>   less memory associated with each visited page as compared to
>   FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when
>   switching between pages.